# What's a better name? is_spam! and make_spam?

Tags: ruby

I saw a presentation http://essential-rails-pattern.heroku.com/#23 (in Chinese)

and it describe a method called `is_spam!` to change something to spam.

My question is if `make_spam!` is a better one?

Comment: @OscarRyz example: I have a post, and I want to change the post's status to spam, I want to write a method to be called. `post.is_spam!` or `post.make_spam!` will change the post's status to spammed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm.... I suppose this is somewhat subjective, but considering most methods in ruby that begin with `is` (but typically end in `?`) return a boolean then I suppose I agree; `make_spam!` is better.  I don't really like the mutating methods though anyway...

By convention I personally would name it `to_spam!`.

Answer (score 0):

How about just spam! ? The ! already implies modification, so it reads "modify to spam"
Then you can have spam? as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why not 'markAsSpam!' ?   'makeSpam!' makes me think you are converting the existing text into spam.

Comment: Thank you, But I'm wondering if `markAsSpam!` is correct. I mean, as I know, in ruby, it should be `mark_as_spam!`, right?

Comment: CamelCase vs underscores is a matter of convention:  you should match the rest of the codebase.  I was just thinking about the meaning of the words.